# AJAX throws error 500 only when PHP function is empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-3

I'm completely puzzled to why this happens, I've been messing on this for a few hours and I'm going crazyyyy! I am trying to update my DB when a checkbox is toggled on or off. The success response works if my PHP function I'm calling is empty, but fails whenever I add PHP. Note I'm on Laravel 3, and I've tried enabling or disabling CSRF filtering, no luck.

**My JS:**

```
$seenTD = $('td.seen_by_user');
$seenTD.each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var $seenLabel = $this.find('label');
    var $seenInput = $this.find(':checkbox');

    $seenInput.change(function() {

        var _csrf = $('input[name="csrf_token"]').val();
        var chkName = $(this).attr('name');
        var checkVal = $(':checkbox[name='+chkName+']').prop('checked'); //true or false
        var id = $this.find('input[name="reminder_id"]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:  'update',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'seen='+checkVal+'&reminder_id='+id+'&csrf_token='+_csrf,

            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);

                if($seenInput.is(':checked')) {
                    $seenLabel.removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
                    $seenLabel.find('span').text('Oui');
                }
                else {
                    $seenLabel.removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
                    $seenLabel.find('span').text('Non');
                }

            }
        });

    });
});
```

**My PHP**

```
public function post_update() {

    $request = Request::instance();
    $content = $request->getContent();

    $id = $content['id'];
    $seen = $content['seen'];

    if($seen == 'true') {
        $seen = 1;
    }
    if($seen == 'false') {
        $seen = 0;
    }

    DB::table('reminders')->where('id', '=', $id)->update(
        array(
            'seen_by_user' => $seen
        ));
}
```

Comment: `public function post_update() {` should be `function post_update() {` I believe. You only use public if it's a function within a class. This will result in a parse error of your script and a 500 error.

Comment: After fixing it, it works with or without public. I am unsure of the difference, however.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of maybe helping someone, as this is my first working AJAX, I'll explain how I got it to work, as well as supply working code. I'm not claiming this is the best way to do it, so if anyone has their word to say, don't hesitate :)

There were multiple issues, from Javascript insconsistency returning the row ID I needed for the database update, to the PHP function, and the way I was grabbing the POST data.

To get it to work, I played on Fiddler, retrieved the error message that Laravel throws at me. And I could debug from there :)

My working code is :

**JS:**

```
$('td.seen_by_user :checkbox').change(function() {

    $this = $(this);
    var $label = $this.siblings('label');
    var id = $this.attr('data-id');
    var _csrf = $this.siblings('input[name="csrf_token"]').val();
    var value = $this.prop('checked');

    $.ajax({
        url:  'update',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"seen_by_user": value, "id": id, "csrf_token": _csrf},

        success: function(data) {

            if($this.is(':checked')) {
                $label.removeClass('unchecked').addClass('checked');
                $label.find('span').text('Oui');
            }
            else {
                $label.removeClass('checked').addClass('unchecked');
                $label.find('span').text('Non');
            }

        }
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
function post_update() {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $seen = $_POST['seen_by_user'];

    if($seen == 'true') {
        $seen = 1;
    }
    if($seen == 'false') {
        $seen = 0;
    }

    $update_reminder = DB::table('reminders')->where('id', '=', $id)->update(
        array('seen_by_user' => $seen));
}
```

**And my HTML** (Blade Template from Laravel, where {{ }} brackets are simply echo's, and @foreach is a )

```
@foreach ($reminders as $reminder)
    ...
    <td class="seen_by_user">
        <form class="ajax" action="update" method="POST">
            {{ Form::token() }}
            {{ Form::checkbox('seen_'.$reminder->id, 1, $reminder->seen_by_user, array('id' => 'seen_'.$reminder->id, 'data-id' => $reminder->id)) }}
            <label class="seen {{ ($reminder->seen_by_user == 1 ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' ) }}"for="{{ 'seen_'.$reminder->id }}"><i class="read"></i><span>{{ ($reminder->seen_by_user == 1 ? 'Oui' : 'Non') }}</span></label>
        </form>
    </td>
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: What specifically fixed your issue? It would be much more helpful if you only posted the changes.

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be an object like this

```
data: {"seen": checkVal, "reminder_id": id, "csrf_token": _csrf},
```

The $.ajax method will take care of the presentation and transmission.

Comment: thank you :) great help but was not my final issue. played with fiddler and could see server error messages, had missing arguments on my function, then had to mess with the js and html to get unique names because the db would update, but it wouldn't select the right row, dropped the hidden field and used html5 data instead, my first working AJAX, yay!